# Group collection by sequent elements equality

Tags: c#, linq

If I have some collection, for example: collection of integers:

```
1 1 2 2 3 3 1 2 3 4 4 1 1 2 3
```

and I need to group only sequent elements, in this example:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
1
2
3
4 4
1 1
2
3
```

I built LINQ expression that create an anonymous collection that have index of element in collection, it's equality marker, then I joined collection with it's shifted forward by one position, and then group elements. But this algorithm, I think, too excess.

Are there more elegant solutions?

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: Does your algorithm work if you have more than two equal elements in a row?  Would it group `1 1 1 2` into `1 1 1` and `2`?  Or would it group it into `1 1`, `1 1`, `2`?

Comment: @YacoubMassad http://pastebin.com/ahGsi4AV

Comment: @user2023861 it has to work with any number of sequent elements

Comment: @dotFive, I only asked because it sounds like your proposed algorithm involving shifting the collection forward one position would treat 3 ones as 2 collections of 2 ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is implementation, which uses LINQ:

```
//Input sequence
int[] input = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3 };
//Group number
int i = 0;
//Result array [<group number>][]
int[][] values = 
    //Select new anonymous object, which contains the source value from input and its group number
    input.Select((item, index) => new { Key = index > 0 ? (item == input[index - 1] ? i : ++i) : 0, Value = item })
    //Group anonymous objects by group number
    .GroupBy(pair => pair.Key)
    //Select values for each group
    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I tried to find method that will allow not initialized collections, but, as I see, it's not possible in this task. so, thanks for such laconic way

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I found a Linq way to do this using the Aggregate extension method.  This method allows you to look at previous items in the collection using the accumulator parameter in the Func lambda.  Here it is:

```
static List<List<int>> Group2(List<int> data)
{
    return data.Aggregate(new List<List<int>>(), (list, item) => 
    {
        if (list.Count == 0 || list[list.Count - 1][0] != item)
        {
            list.Add(new List<int> { item });
        }
        else
        {
            list[list.Count - 1].Add(item);
        }
        return list;
    });
}
```

---

I can't think of a Linq way to do this because I don't think any of its methods allow you to look at previous items in that way.  Here's a generic way I'd do it:

```
static IEnumerable<List<T>> Group<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, IEqualityComparer<T> comp)
{
    T previous = default(T);
    bool previousExists = false;
    var eee = list.GetEnumerator();
    List<T> result = null;

    while(eee.MoveNext())
    {
        T current = eee.Current;
        if (previousExists && comp.Equals(current, previous))
        {
            result.Add(current);
        }
        else
        {
            if (result != null)
                yield return result;
            result = new List<T> { current };
        }
        previous = current;
        previousExists = true;
    }

    if (result != null)
        yield return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't really need LINQ - just simple loop will do the job:

```
var res = new List<List<int>>();
foreach(int i in data)
{
    var c = res.Count;
    if (c == 0 || res[c - 1][0] != i)
        res.Add(new List<int>() { i });
    else
        res[c - 1].Add(i);
}
```

You can also use linq with external variable, but this will probably be harder to read

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that LINQ is missing a `Select` method that lets you tap into the previous result.

If it did, you would simply need to write something like this:

```
var sequences = items
    .SelectWithPreviousResult(
        new { Item = -1, GroupNumber = 0 }, // default result (used for first item)
        (item, previous) => new
        {
            Item = item,
            GroupNumber = previous.Item == x
                ? previous.GroupNumber
                : previous.GroupNumber + 1 })
    .GroupBy(x => x.GroupNumber, x => x.Item);
```

What this does is select the current item along with a `GroupNumber` that starts at 0 and increments only when the current item differs from the previous item. Then it groups by `GroupNumber` and simplifies the group members to just items.

Of course, the above will not compile because `SelectWithPrevious` does not yet exist. The nice thing about LINQ, though, is that you can write your own extension methods quite easily. The `SelectWithPreviousResult` method could be implemented like this:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectWithPreviousResult<TSource, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> items,
        TResult defaultResult,
        Func<TSource, TResult, TResult> func)
    {
        var previousResult = defaultResult;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var result = func(item, previousResult);
            previousResult = result;
            yield return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Advantages of implementing it this way are that you could reuse the extension method to solve similar problems, and your code gains some readability versus using a pure loop or a complex `Aggregate` expression.

Comment: thanks, it would be interesting to use such extension method